# ¿Cómo ordenar los registros por precio correctamente?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `select` que al seleccionar una opción llama un código `javascript`, el código permite ordenar los registro, tomando los datos de la clase `product` dentro de la clase `product-container` que es repetitivo para cada resultado.

El script que tengo funciona correctamente con `cadenas de texto` pero los números no los ordena correctamente, revisando el método `sort()` entiendo por qué, pero no sé como aplicarlo a este código.

El código que tengo actualmente los ordena de esta manera:

```
const puntos = [1, 10, 2, 21];
puntos.sort(); // [1, 10, 2, 21]
```

El número `2` lo cloca después del `10` y allí pierde el orden de menor a mayor, entiendo que de esta manera se resuelve:

```
const numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
    numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
       return a - b;
});

console.log(numbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Pero no sé aplicarlo al código que tengo:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.spa').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var products = $('.product-container').find('div.product');
        $(products).show();

        var divList = $(".product");
        divList.sort(function(a, b) {
          return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('price'), $(b).data('price'));
        });
        
        $(".product-container").html(divList);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Intenté cosas que se me ocurrieron, por ejemplo:

```
return $(a).data('price') - $(b).data('price');
```

también:

```
return a - b;
```

también cambié `String` por `Number`

```
return Number.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('price'), $(b).data('price'));
```

Pero no sé mucho de `Javascript` y no sé como resolverlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumo que lo que guardas en el atributo price es un valor numérico, el precio de algún producto:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('li').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data("price") - $(b).data("price")
  })
  .appendTo($('ul'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li data-price="5">5.00 </li>
<li data-price="1.40">1.40 </li>
<li data-price="2.40">2.40 </li>
<li data-price="1.10">1.10 </li>
</ul>
<button>Sort</button>
```

Al usar la operación resta, Javascript va a convertir los valores en números (no se puede restar texto y a Javascript no le gusta generar errores, así que intenta cambiar el tipo a lo que pueda operar). Tras eso, con la función de jQuery appendTo los elementos son "sacados" del documento y vueltos a insertar en el nuevo orden.

Comment: Muchas gracias! mejoró pero aún tengo unos pequeños errores. Pero si es la solución, debo revisar mi código.

Comment: Gracias, ya está resuelto. Tenía una cadena de texto para agregar los decimales a los número, al quitarlos funcionó perfectamente.